# GE Profile refridgerator water dispenser issue

Tags: refrigerator

When I dispense water it will come out fast and slow down to nothing before 20 oz is dipensed. If I wait a while it will do exactly the same. I have tried a new filter with same results.

Comment: How old is the fridge? There could be a clog in the line. When the dispenser is not engaged then enough pressure builds up past the blockage but slows down to a crawl once you try to fill your glass of water.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The fridge is 14 years old.

Comment: These old fridges really suck with water dispensation. I've read that they often freeze. It might make sense that your water is thawed at a certain part of the line, then you're getting an obstruction of ice chunks.

Comment: the water supply line is slow to refill the fridge's chilled water reservoir, which is sized for two small or one large drink. Clear upstream obstructions like deposits and kinks.